# Does the query builder prevent SQL Injection?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

Hi all i'm currently working in ASP.NET using the query builder to create select, insert, update queries etc etc on some datasets which i have created in my App_Code folder. I have realised for you to use a parameters in the queries you have to use a "?" like so

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?
```

what i was wondering is does this actually protect your tables from sql injection or do you need to do more in the code in order to protect the queries?

Answer (score 3):

Parameterized queries accept parameters and input them as the appropriate SQL data type. So for example creating this proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStudent (IN LN VARCHAR(200))
  BEGIN
    SELECT Name FROM Students WHERE LastName = LN;
  END
```

And passing this value (assume this is in your C# code.

```
"'Bobby'; DROP TABLE STUDENTS;"
```

Will essentially execute this query

```
SELECT Name FROM Students WHERE LastName ='''Bobby;''DROP TABLE Students'
```

Which is quite safe.

Of course, you will have to adapt for your particular application needs, but the general point is that parameterized queries are safe against SQL Injection for all major RDMSs.

Comment: Hi Nick thanks for your reply but what you suggested doesn't seem to work :( But i with the way that my query is it still vunerable to sql injection ?

Comment: I set up the query like you have if doesn't return anything also when i create it i get a warning telling me the syntax is invalid